# OpenCV, webcam window not opening

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision

I am very new to computer vision and using the OpenCV libraries for some basic functions like opening a window for the camera. I used the code from the OpenCV book I run a code from there. A part is shown below:

```
def run(self):
        """Run the main loop"""
        self._windowManager.createWindow()
        while self._windowManager.isWindowCreated:
            self._captureManager.enterFrame()
            frame = self._captureManager.frame

            self._captureManager.exitFrame()
            self._windowManager.processEvents()
```

I get the following error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'nameWindow'
```

And this the line it points to:

```
    139     def createWindow (self):
    140            cv2.namedWindow(self._windowName)
--> 141            self._isWindowCreated = True
    142     def show(self, frame):
    143            cv2.imshow(self._windowName, frame)
```

Can someone help me what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to say from the code what the problem is, but I believe is `cv2.namedWindow()`not `nameWindow`. Also, add `cv2.waitKey(1)` after the `imshow()` function call.

Here's a simpler way to open the webcam using python and opencv:

```
import cv2
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("Window")

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    cv2.imshow("Window", frame)

    #This breaks on 'q' key
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem was being from my side. I didn't restart the kernel completely. Which is why it was giving me the same error even though I fixed it.
The only question is, why was the complier giving me one error at a time and not all errors at once.